# Import from Web with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am having trouble reading the description and price with code below. This code opens the first 4 pages from Miami Craigslist auto page and read to Excel the description and price. The code successfully opens the first 4 pages:

```
    Sub fortesting()

    Dim link As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim blog As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim price As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim html  As HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String
    Dim URLParameter As String
    Dim page As Long, counter As Long
    'Dim http As Object
    Dim links As Object
    Dim blogpost As Object
    Dim priceonly As Object
    Dim Results As Object
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim increment As Integer
    Dim htmlele1 As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim ss As Integer
    Dim ee As Integer
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim q As Integer

    q = Format(k, "0")

   ' This is the first cell that a blog post hyperlink is created in
    Set StartCell = Range("A1")

    URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' CHnage this to False if you want to hide IE
    IE.Visible = True

    counter = 0
    page = 0


    'Set the number of pages of the website to go through in the browser
    For page = 0 To 4 Step 1  'increment by 1 - total 4 pages
    Debug.Print page
   
    If page >= 0 Then URLParameter = "#search=1~list~" & page & "~0"

    IE.navigate URL & URLParameter
    
     'Wait for the browser to load the page
     Do Until IE.readyState = 4
    
        DoEvents
        
     Loop

     Set html = IE.document
     Set links = html.getElementsByTagName("h3")
     Index = 0

     For Each link In links
                        
        If InStr(LCase(link.outerHTML), "result-heading") Then
    
            Set blogpost = link.getElementsByTagName("title-blob")
            Set priceonly = link.getElementsByClassName("priceinfo")
            Set Results = html.getElementsByClassName("result-row")
            For Each blog In blogpost
                        
                StartCell.Offset(counter, 0).Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=StartCell.Offset(counter, 0), Address:=blog, _
                TextToDisplay:=link.innerText
                
                StartCell.Offset(counter, 1).Value = 
              Results(Index).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
                                    
                Index = Index + 1
            Next blog
            
           counter = counter + 1
            
        End If
    
        Next link
            
        Next page

        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
   
   
        Columns("B:B").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            Columns("D:D").Select
            Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy;@"
     
      
   

         End Sub
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I just need to read the description and price. For example:
RANGE("A1") = 2008 Cadillac Escalade
RANGE("B1") = $8,500

Comment: According to the URL provided the HTML code contains this <p>We've detected that JavaScript is not enabled in your browser. You must enable JavaScript to use craigslist.</p>. That is a normal way to hide info from automated web crawlers on the web ;-)

Comment: Hello Svein - I just checked, Craigslist is enable in Microsoft Edge. I cant open IE it switches automatically to Edge.
Is there a way to modify code so it uses Chrome instead?

Comment: It has nothing to do with what browser user have. It is where the data is located. If data is located in the html it is possible to fetch by reading the code line by line and look for html tags and pick up the values with InStr(), Mid() and stuff. I can post you an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you put this Function in a module it can be called to download any html (or any other file from the web) - and return the result in your 'ToFile' on your computer.

```
Function download(URL, ToFile) As Boolean
On Error GoTo feil
download = True
' Parameter for funsjon overføres
    strFileURL = URL                    ' eks "http://norsktipping.n3sport.no/default.aspx?event=GETMATCHINFO&NTMatchId=209562"
    strHDLocation = ToFile              ' eks "file.htm"
 
' Hent filen
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 
    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
    Sv = objXMLHTTP.send()
    
    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
 
      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
 
      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
      Set objFSO = Nothing

      objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End If
 
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
 Exit Function

feil:
If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then MsgBox ("Workbook is in read only mode! This result in error when using the dll for web.")
 
download = False
Resume Next
End Function
```

And if I test it towards our URLs it takes the HTML, but not the result of the js (Java Script) that returns a InnerHtml element to the web page. You can use the function like this:

```
Sub TestDownload()
'URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta#search=1~list~1~0"
URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
Sv = download(URL, "C:\Temp\TempHtmlFile.txt")

If Sv = True And Dir("C:\Temp\TempHtmlFile.txt") <> "" Then
FileNum = FreeFile
        Open "C:\Temp\TempHtmlFile.txt" For Input As #FileNum
        While Not EOF(FileNum)
            Line Input #FileNum, MyTxt ' Read one line to MyTxt and work with it in VBA
             MsgBox MyTxt
             MsgBox Len(MyTxt)
        Wend
        Close #FileNum
Else
MsgBox "Download of file failed"
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
with this just get the lines of the site in column A. So you can using formulas to find the parts you need in columns B, C...

    Option Explicit

'the code must be in the unit of the sheet you want to downCopy the data
Private Sub downCopy(Optional startCopyAt As String = "A1", Optional fromPage As Integer = 0, Optional toPage As Integer = 4)
   Dim link As HTMLLinkElement, IE As Object, URL As String, URLParameter As String
   Dim page As Long, counter As Long, links As Object, StartCell As Range
   
   Set StartCell = Me.Range(startCopyAt)  ' This is the first cell that a blog post hyperlink is created in
   URL = "https://miami.craigslist.org/search/cta"
   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   counter = 0
   page = 0
   With IE
      .Visible = True   ' CHnage this to False if you want to hide IE
      For page = fromPage To toPage
         URLParameter = "#search=1~list~" & page & "~0"
         .navigate URL & URLParameter
         Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
         Do While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
         Loop
         Set links = .document.getElementsByClassName("result-node-wide")
         For Each link In links
            StartCell.Offset(counter, 0).Value = link.outerHTML
            counter = counter + 1
         Next link
      Next page
      .Quit
   End With
   Set IE = Nothing
End Sub


'call the function like this:
Private Sub callDownCopy()
   Call downCopy 'with default parameters
   'Call downCopy("B5", 0, 2) ' or set other parameters
   'Call downCopy("namedRange", 4, 7) ' set other parameters with a named range
End Sub
```

'I added a delay after the navigation

[image: here can see the end of the first lines]

[image: and here the starting of the lines]

Comment: Hi -  I copied your code to a ew module, I am getting a compile error (Invalid or Unqualified reference). The error is at this line:
.Hyperlinks.Add _

Comment: the line with the .Hyperlinks.Add and many others are commented out. This code is not "ready to use". It saves all data in A column. Then you have to extract any parts you need ... The commented code is useless.

Comment: understood. I ran the code but I do not see any data in column A. What am I missing?

Comment: the code must be in the unit of the sheet you want to downCopy the data. (My system is Windows10 and office2007. The code don't work in windows11)

Comment: still not reading any data. The code runs fine and the web pages are open but no data downloaded. Did you test it? Can you share a screenshot of your result?

Comment: Why am I not seeing any data. Code seems to run fine

Comment: Sometimes if for any reasom IE blocks, seems to run very quickly but it does nothing. I will change the code to delete unused variables. Restart your computer, copy the new code just now tested again AND run it in debugging mode step by step with F8

Comment: Hi - The code is running fine, I see the pages open. I dont see any data dump. This is strange.

Comment: Create another new excel file, copy only this code to a sheet and test it.

Comment: Created a new file, ran the code, web pages open but no data downloaded into Column A still